# Python - Loading Zip Codes into a DataFrame as Strings?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, zipcode

I'm using Pandas to load an Excel spreadsheet which contains zip code (e.g. 32771). The zip codes are stored as 5 digit strings in spreadsheet. When they are pulled into a DataFrame using the command...

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile("5-Digit-Zip-Codes.xlsx")
dfz = xls.parse('Zip Codes')
```

they are converted into numbers. So '00501' becomes 501.

So my questions are, how do I:

a. Load the DataFrame and keep the string type of the zip codes stored in the Excel file?

b. Convert the numbers in the DataFrame into a five digit string e.g. "501" becomes "00501"?

Answer (score 8):

As a workaround, you could convert the `int`s to 0-padded strings of length 5 using [`Series.str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html#pandas.Series.str.zfill):

```
df['zipcode'] = df['zipcode'].astype(str).str.zfill(5)
```

---

Demo:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'zipcode':['00501']})
df.to_excel('/tmp/out.xlsx')
xl = pd.ExcelFile('/tmp/out.xlsx')
df = xl.parse('Sheet1')
df['zipcode'] = df['zipcode'].astype(str).str.zfill(5)
print(df)
```

yields

```
  zipcode
0   00501
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid panda's type inference with a custom converter, e.g. if `'zipcode'` was the header of the column with zipcodes:

```
dfz = xls.parse('Zip Codes', converters={'zipcode': lambda x:x})
```

This is arguably a bug since the column was originally string encoded, made an issue [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11331)

Comment: if you have `00501` in excel, numeric with 2 leading zeroes, that would give `501` in pandas....

Answer (score 1):

```
str(my_zip).zfill(5)
```

or

```
print("{0:>05s}".format(str(my_zip)))
```

are 2 of many many ways to do this

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers have correctly suggested using `zfill(5)`. However, if your zipcodes are already in `float` datatype for some reason (I recently encountered data like this), you first need to convert it to `int`. Then you can use `zfill(5)`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'zipcode':[11.0, 11013.0]})
```

```
    zipcode
0   11.0
1   11013.0
```

```
df['zipcode'] = df['zipcode'].astype(int).astype(str).str.zfill(5)
```

```
    zipcode
0   00011
1   11013
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas.read_excel docs say that you can preserve the data exactly as in the Excel sheet by specifying dtype as `object`:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

> dtypeType name or dict of column -> type, default None
> Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32} Use object to preserve data as stored in Excel and not interpret dtype. If converters are specified, they will be applied INSTEAD of dtype conversion.

So, something like this should work:

```
xls = pd.read_excel("5-Digit-Zip-Codes.xlsx", dtype=dtype={'zip_code': object, 'other_col': str})
```

(note: not at my work pc right now, so wasn't able to test it yet)