# Python read excel file error beginning zeros error

Tags: python

I have a  Excel file 'test.xls' file which I could read in as following:

```
    df=  pd.read_excel('test.xls',sep='\t',header=1)
```

I checked df and found there is a column zip_code which contain zip code like 00051, 00123, but the first 0 was cut off while the system read in the excel file.

So that column will be 51, 123. How could I keep the first zeros intact while reading the file? Thanks.
Found solution as I posted below.

Comment: it converted text to integer, check if you can in read_excel declare type of data in columns. Or use string formating to convert integers to string with leading zeros.

Comment: use a dictionary to set `dtype` of the column considered

Comment: Since the OP found the answer in the linked question, this should be closed as a duplicate of [Python pandas: how to specify data types when reading an Excel file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591466/python-pandas-how-to-specify-data-types-when-reading-an-excel-file)

Comment: Except by reading the previous comment (Tony), there is no indication that is related to the `pandas` library.  I suggest adding the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Found a answer here:

[Python pandas: how to specify data types when reading an Excel file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591466/python-pandas-how-to-specify-data-types-when-reading-an-excel-file):

You just specify converters. I created an excel spreadsheet of the following structure:

```
    names   ages
    bob     05
    tom     4
    suzy    3
```

Where the "ages" column is formatted as strings. To load:

import pandas as pd

```
   df =      pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx',sheetname='Sheet1',header=0,converters={'names':str,'ages':str})
```

> > > ```
> > >  df
> > >       names ages
> > >   0   bob   05
> > >   1   tom   4
> > >   2   suzy  3
> > > ```

Thanks @tnknepp

Comment: I tried  the above converter but still have the problem. I checked the original Excel file , the zip code was stored as zip code format. I finally found this to work around:                       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137686/python-loading-zip-codes-into-a-dataframe-as-strings                            df['zipcode'] = df['zipcode'].astype(str).str.zfill(5)