# Read Excel document's cells as string

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to read everything in excel document, that looks like this:

[image]

When we read the excel file

`xls = pd.ExcelFile('media/No2.xls')`

We are getting a problem in column 2.
Instead of getting us:

```
    code
    444444444505
    444444444506
    444444444506
    777777777001
    000000000025
    000000000029
    000000000044
    000000000045
    code
    111111111111
    111111111127
    000000001341
```

it gives us next:

```
    code
    444444444505
    444444444506
    444444444506
    777777777001
    25
    29
    44
    45
    code
    111111111111
    111111111127
    1341
```

We need that `000000001341` to stay as `000000001341`, not `1341`( and also other numbers with 0s infront of em). In order to fix this issue we tried, well, everything we could find!

```
dtype='str'\ str \ 'string' \ object \ 'object' \ whatever

converters={"2": object\string}, converters = object\string.
```

In end? No changes. It still reads `000000001341` as integer and outputs it as `1341`.

Comment: is it possible to share the excel file as a download? that way I can have a look at it and proffer solutions; and others can as well

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/91as6bl855v0y2hoc19hm/TestDocument.xls?dl=0&rlkey=chq52zexvabp89h8wqbi7mxxw

Here is a link for heavily edited(due to privacy reasons) document, that we are working with. The problem comes when trying to extract cells containing "00000001341" and 
"00000003005".

Though diving into document itself, we found out that the format type of the cells is 
some kind of Numer PESEL. From the looks of it, it transforms 1341 into 000000001341, but we are still getting 1341 when it reads the cell.

Comment: Is the length of that field fixed? Maybe you can convert it to string after importing and add back the leading zeroes as needed. `df['column_name'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.rjust(12, '0') if x.isnumeric() else x)`. Edit: similar workaround posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33138107

Comment: The problem is - it isn't.
IF it would be always "N amount of numbers" - it would be all good, and we'd gone the way of adding the numbers. Easy.
But it varies from good to good and we cannot exactly predict how many numbers(or in our case - 0s) to put infront of a number.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly the type of field you're working with, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PESEL, but according to that WIKI entry, all PESEL numbers are 11 digits long. If that's the case, then you can simply use `zfill(11)` or `rjust(11,'0')` after converting to string.

Comment: I just created an xls file with the data in the image, and for values under code, I prefixed with apostrophe "'" so that the content in the cell is treated as string and zeros are not lost. In absence of apostrophe, excel removes the leading zeros. When I read using pd.read_excel, it read with the zeros. Essentially, I'm missing something in reproducing the issue in question i/e., I can't reproduce :(

Comment: Naveed, try using the file I provided above.

StevenS, the numbers that are coming are usually 13 digits long, or 8, or unique to document sender code with varying length.

I cannot predict each good's number count.

But with your info- It is interesting to find out if I can find an individual cell's format.

If I will, it will be a solution to problem I have, and I won't need to look for a way to extract it as string.

Comment: Ok. Think I found a solution. Question: can we assume that all your codes (in your real, non-edited file) are in the same column, our notorious `'Unnamed: 6'`? Would make life slightly easier if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. It turns out, based on the file you supplied, that the values in your file that *look like* strings are in fact simply integers. They look like string, because they have formatting "Special". E.g.:

[image]

But if we apply format "General", we see that it's just a number:

[image]

This is the reason why something like `xls = pd.read_excel('media/No2.xls', converters={2:str})` has no effect, even if it is applied to the correct column index.

I've turned to `xlrd` for a different solution. With `xlrd` you can trace the number format of the cells in the sheets by adding `formatting_info=True`, when loading the workbook. Basically, the code below iterates over all rows and colums in the first sheet (assuming that this is the correct one) and retrieves the number format of each cell.

E.g. for the cell shown in the image above ("1341", *formatted* as "00000001341"), the returned value will be "00000000000". For all potential formats of this type ("0","00", etc.), we check if `xls.iloc[row,col]` contains an integer. If so, we change the integer to a string and add the required leading zeros by overwriting `xls.iloc[row,col]` with `str(xls.iloc[row,col]).zfill(len(format_str))`, as required. I've added a print statement for the cells that will be changed, so that you can track in the console, whether all changes make sense.

Code is as follows. Let me know if you still experience any difficulties.

```
import pandas as pd

# import xls, first sheet with header == None
xls = pd.read_excel('media/No2.xls', header=None)

import xlrd

# add formatting_info=True to allow for retrieving number format
book = xlrd.open_workbook('media/No2.xls', formatting_info=True)

sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)

# xlrd uses 0-index for rows, cols, e.g.: sh.cell(0,0) == A1

# from the mock data I collected the following unique formats.
# I'm assuming we only need to deal with the long strings of zeros
# the code below takes into account the possibility that the real data 
# has more of these variants
# =============================================================================
# formats = ['0',
#            '0000000', # this one
#            '0" "',
#            '00000000000', # this one
#            '#,##0.00',
#            '0.000',
#            '0000000000', # this one
#            '0.00',
#            'General']
# =============================================================================

# iterate over all rows (get length from xls DataFrame)
for row in range(xls.shape[0]):
    
    # iterate over all cols (get length from xls DataFrame)
    for col in range(xls.shape[1]):
        
        # get format cell
        cell = sh.cell(row,col)   
        xf_index = cell.xf_index
        xf = book.xf_list[xf_index]
        format_key = xf.format_key
        format = book.format_map[format_key]
        format_str = format.format_str
        
        # if format like "0", "00", etc. and corresponding value in xls is an integer, define new string
        if len(format_str) == format_str.count('0') and isinstance(xls.iloc[row, col],int):
            temp = str(xls.iloc[row,col]).zfill(len(format_str))
            
            # if new string (== temp) is same as the one already in xls, do nothing
            # else: overwrite value
            if str(xls.iloc[row,col]) != temp:
                print(f'r{row} format: {format_str}; \timport: {xls.iloc[row,col]};' +
                      f'\tchanged to: {str(xls.iloc[row,col]).zfill(len(format_str))}')
                xls.iloc[row,col] = str(xls.iloc[row,col]).zfill(len(format_str))
```

Comment: You're a legend! Thanks alot for help!
We used your code(With some adaptations ofc.), and it works smooth like butter now.

Answer (score 1):

Try either:

```
xls = pd.read_excel('media/No2.xls', converters={'code':str})
```

or:

```
xls = pd.read_excel('media/No2.xls', converters={2:str})
```

By default [pd.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) will use the first row in the sheet as the column names of the DataFrame. So, to set the conversion, you need to reference the correct column either by name ('code') or by index (2, but without qoutes!).

Comment: We already TRIED all the converters.

converters={"2": object\string}, converters = object\string. - Specifically line of text where it says that we did that.
Result of that? It still, sadly, reads as integer.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of your claim. But here you are saying that you tried `converters={"2": object\string}`. In my answer, I am explicitly saying that you need to try `{2:str}`, so the number 2 *without* the quotation marks. Moreover, I am suggesting you add this snippet as a parameter to `pd.read_excel()`, not `pd.ExcelFile()`. The body of your question gives no indication that you are using `pd.read_excel()`.

Comment: Sadly, did not work.
https://i.imgur.com/FGEMVOw.png

Comment: In the file you just sent, the data in question is not in column with index 2, but in 6. Doesn't matter much: I just tried, and that also doesn't work. Not sure about the actual setup of this file type. Doesn't look like a regular `.xls` at all. Never mind. Other approach, you mention (and I can see it here as well) that these are PESEL numbers. These are apparently always 11 digits long. If you are sure they are all PESEL numbers, you could just re-add the leading zeros after loading the file.

Comment: JUST realised dumb mistake we made.
We did put 2:str, instead of 6:str(Where the column with problematic number is), result, is sadly - same.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to read in the data as individual rows, manipulate the data to your specification to get your adjusted values. This is one way of doing it; I believe you can optimise it further. I will be using [xlsx_cells](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/io/#janitor.io.xlsx_cells) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to read in the data:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

content = jn.xlsx_cells('Downloads/TestDocument.xlsx', include_blank_cells=False)

numbers = content.loc[content.number_format.ne('General') & content.data_type.eq('n')]

In [65]: numbers
Out[65]:
    value internal_value coordinate  row  column data_type  is_date number_format
38      1              1        B24   24       2         n    False             0
39      2              2        C24   24       3         n    False             0
40      3              3        G24   24       7         n    False             0
41      9              9        T24   24      20         n    False             0
42     10             10        W24   24      23         n    False             0
43     11             11        Y24   24      25         n    False             0
44     12             12       AB24   24      28         n    False             0
45     13             13       AG24   24      33         n    False             0
46     14             14       AI24   24      35         n    False             0
47     15             15       AL24   24      38         n    False             0
48      1              1        B25   25       2         n    False             0
49      2              2        B26   26       2         n    False             0
51   1341           1341        G26   26       7         n    False   00000000000
52      6              6        W26   26      23         n    False         0.000
53   81.9           81.9        Y26   26      25         n    False          0.00
54  491.4          491.4       AL26   26      38         n    False          0.00
55      3              3        B27   27       2         n    False             0
56      4              4        B28   28       2         n    False             0
57      5              5        B29   29       2         n    False             0
58      6              6        B30   30       2         n    False             0
60   3005           3005        G30   30       7         n    False   00000000000
61     12             12        W30   30      23         n    False         0.000
62   59.4           59.4        Y30   30      25         n    False          0.00
63  712.8          712.8       AL30   30      38         n    False          0.00
64      7              7        B31   31       2         n    False             0
65     10             10        B34   34       2         n    False             0
66     11             11        B35   35       2         n    False             0
67     12             12        B36   36       2         n    False             0
68     13             13        B37   37       2         n    False             0
```

The number_format gives us what we need; let's tweak that to our advantage:

```py
condition = numbers.number_format.str.contains('.', regex = False)
decimals = np.where(condition, 
                    numbers
                    .number_format
                    .str.split('\.')
                    .str[-1]
                    .str
                    .len(), 
                     0)

lengths = numbers.value.astype(str).str.len()
if_no_decimals = [x[:-z] + str(y) 
                  for x, y, z 
                  in zip(numbers.number_format, numbers.value, lengths)]

decimals = [f"{x:.{y}f}" 
            for x, y 
            in zip(numbers.value, decimals)]

new_values = np.select([~condition, condition], 
                       [if_no_decimals, decimals], 
                       0)

numbers.assign(new_values = new_values)

    value internal_value coordinate  row  column data_type  is_date number_format   new_values
38      1              1        B24   24       2         n    False             0            1
39      2              2        C24   24       3         n    False             0            2
40      3              3        G24   24       7         n    False             0            3
41      9              9        T24   24      20         n    False             0            9
42     10             10        W24   24      23         n    False             0           10
43     11             11        Y24   24      25         n    False             0           11
44     12             12       AB24   24      28         n    False             0           12
45     13             13       AG24   24      33         n    False             0           13
46     14             14       AI24   24      35         n    False             0           14
47     15             15       AL24   24      38         n    False             0           15
48      1              1        B25   25       2         n    False             0            1
49      2              2        B26   26       2         n    False             0            2
51   1341           1341        G26   26       7         n    False   00000000000  00000001341
52      6              6        W26   26      23         n    False         0.000        6.000
53   81.9           81.9        Y26   26      25         n    False          0.00        81.90
54  491.4          491.4       AL26   26      38         n    False          0.00       491.40
55      3              3        B27   27       2         n    False             0            3
56      4              4        B28   28       2         n    False             0            4
57      5              5        B29   29       2         n    False             0            5
58      6              6        B30   30       2         n    False             0            6
60   3005           3005        G30   30       7         n    False   00000000000  00000003005
61     12             12        W30   30      23         n    False         0.000       12.000
62   59.4           59.4        Y30   30      25         n    False          0.00        59.40
63  712.8          712.8       AL30   30      38         n    False          0.00       712.80
64      7              7        B31   31       2         n    False             0            7
65     10             10        B34   34       2         n    False             0           10
66     11             11        B35   35       2         n    False             0           11
67     12             12        B36   36       2         n    False             0           12
68     13             13        B37   37       2         n    False             0           13
```

In short, the logic for munging or modifying the columns, you know best. Hopefully this sets you in the right direction. Under the hood `xlsx_cells` uses openpyxl to get the data, and works only with `xlsx` files - I had to convert the shared data from xls to xlsx.